# Jquery/JS Progress bars change class on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple progress bar where the click event changes the class according to my CSS classes:

so what i need to do is determine what the current class is and change the last character of the class so if the current bar is:

and the user clicks on the next button:

the script would be?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.progress-next', function() {
  //1. get current step-?
  //2. incriment current step + 1
  //3. remove current step-? from .progress-bar (once i know how to handle getting the classes i have this part :) 
  //4. add new incremented class to .progress-bar (once i know how to handle getting the classes i have this part :)
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  &.step-1 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  &.step-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  &.step-3 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  &.step-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped step-1 active">Start</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default progress-next">Next</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you try the pseudo-script you provided ? What's wrong with it ?

Comment: with a globar var? indexStep = 1; and increment it inside the (doc).click()

Comment: I personally feel this would be neater and easier if you used the data attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). That way you can set and interrogate that instead of trying to find the right number within a specific class.

Comment: @MarkWalters it's late i don't know why i didnt think of that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should be what you are looking for.

I left your steps so you can follow the code and what it does.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.progress-next', function() {
  //1. get current step-?
  
  var cl = $(".progress-bar").attr("class").split(/\s/).filter(function( cn ) {
        return cn.indexOf('step') === 0;
    });
  //console.log(cl)
  
  //2. incriment current step + 1
  var step = parseInt(cl[0].split('-')[1]) + 1;
  //console.log(step)
  
  //3. remove current step-? from .progress-bar (once i know how to handle getting the classes i have this part :) 
  var newclass = "step-" + step;
  //console.log(newclass)
  
  //4. add new incremented class to .progress-bar (once i know how to handle getting the classes i have this part :) 
  $(".progress-bar").removeClass(cl[0]).addClass(newclass)
  
})
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: blue;
}

.progress-bar.step-1 {
  width: 25%;
}

.progress-bar.step-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.progress-bar.step-3 {
  width: 75%;
}

.progress-bar.step-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped step-1 active">Start</div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default progress-next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the fourth step doesn't need incrementing, it's only 3 steps that you really need to check. So you could simply check for those 3 classes with `$('.progress-bar').hasClass('step-1')`, `$('.progress-bar').hasClass('step-2')` and `$('.progress-bar').hasClass('step-3')`.

Or make a little loop to shorten the code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.progress-next', function() {
  var $progressbar = $('.progress-bar');
  for (var i = 1; i<4; i++) {
    var className = 'step-'+i;
    if ($progressbar.hasClass(className)) {
      $progressbar.removeClass(className).addClass('step-'+(i+1));
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
}

.progress-bar.step-1 {
  width: 25%;
}

.progress-bar.step-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.progress-bar.step-3 {
  width: 75%;
}

.progress-bar.step-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped step-1 active">Start</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default progress-next">Next</button>
```

Comment: @SandraWillford Of course, I just wanted to give you another option because all three answers take a different approach. Pick whichever one you like :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into that snippet.
I changed something in your CSS, because i didn't know what the `&` signs meant.
I also added a variable `current` which got the current state of your bar.

```js
//init the state of the bar
var current = 1;
$('.progress-bar').addClass('step-' + current)
//function to increase by buttonclick
$(document).on('click', '.progress-next', function() {
  $('.progress-bar').removeClass('step-' + current)
  current = current + 1
  $('.progress-bar').addClass('step-' + current)
})
```

```css
.progress-bar {
background: red;
}
.step-1 {
    width: 25%;
  }
 .step-2 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .step-3 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .step-4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar">Start</div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default progress-next">Next</button>
```

Comment: the & is used for attaching classes to each other when nesting SASS/SCSS

Comment: OK I understand